# QT Quick Application Window embed C++ object

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2

I have a QT Quick 2.2 `ApplicationWindow` and I want to use inside this `ApplicationWindow` a C++ object.

I know `QQuickView` view, but this work only for objects which are derived from `QQuickItem` (not for `ApplicationWindow`).

I also know `qmlRegisterType`, but this adds only a general C++ class in QML. I want only to have one C++ object (instantiated in C++ code) in the `ApplicationWindow`.

Is there a possibility to use a C++ Object in a QT Quick 2.2 `ApplicationWindow`?

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "myclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyClass myClass;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

myclass.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class MyClass  : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent = 0) {};
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getValue();
};
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <QString>

QString MyClass::getValue() {
    return "42";
}
```

qrc:///main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    Text {
        text: myClass.getValue()
        anchors.centerIn: parent
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Read about `qmlRegisterType`

Comment: Also: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html

This question has been covered many times here, although I can't find a similar one that would be considered a duplicate...

Comment: according to your update you can choose my 2nd solution in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends or your purpose. If you want to [define QML type from C++,](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html) you should do this in your main.cpp for example :

```
qmlRegisterType< MyClass >("com.example.myclass", 1, 0, "MyClass");
```

now in your .qml file, first you need to import your newly created data type using `import` statement :

```
import com.example.myclass 1.0
```

and then you can create an item from your own data type:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import com.example.myclass 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    Text {
        text: myClass.getValue()
        anchors.centerIn: parent
   }
    MyClass {

   }

}
```

But you have another solution. You can pass a `QObject` object from c++ to QML.

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myClass", new MyClass);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
```

Now inside of your qml file you can access myClass object.

Comment: Your second solution is what I want. Thank you for this. However I have still a little problem, I get in the console 'ReferenceError: myClass is not defined'.

Comment: setContextProperty must be before engine.load

Comment: @saeed Could you change in your solution engine.load...  and engine.rootContext... , if somebody has the same problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3734670 did it before :)